# How to display images using freemarker loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, freemarker

I am writing a freemarker template that displays the star ratings automatically as follows, however I am having trouble to loop through and display "stars" images according to the star ratings calculated:

```
[#assign starRatingsRaw = "${product.landRating}"]
[#assign numOnly = starRatingsRaw?replace(" Star","")]
[#assign numOnly = numOnly?number]
[#assign starCnt = numOnly?int]
${starCnt}

[#list ["<img src="/img/global/graphics/star.gif"/>"] as x]
     ${x}
[/#list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[#if starCnt > 0]
   [#list 1..starCnt as level]
      <img src="/img/global/graphics/star.gif"/>
   [/#list]
[/#if]
```

or more typically with gray trailing stars:

```
[#list 1..5 as level]
    <img src="/img/global/graphics/star[#if starCnt > level]-gray[#if].gif"/>
[/#list]
```